# GridView selection/Button click refresh complete page. How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

Though this question is asked multiple times here, but still asking because I am not able to find a satisfactory answer for this.
I have two grids in the asp page along with some buttons. Now on button click or gridview row selection, complete page refreshes. Also, on selection of one gridview row, I have to update another gridview.
Well, I found a solution- using `UpdatePanel`.

**The Problem starts here- UpdatePanel makes the gridview very slow comparative to default behaviour.**

PS: I also looked out for the reason and found that Updatepanel do some background caching, and thus suggested to clear the caching on page load. 
So I used this code to clear the useless data-

```
    <script language ="javascript" type ="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_BeginRequest(clearDisposableItems)
    function clearDisposableItems(sender, args) {
        if (Sys.Browser.agent == Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer) {
            $get('<%=gridView1.ClientID%>').tBodies[0].removeNode(true);
            $get('<%=gridView2.ClientID%>').tBodies[0].removeNode(true);
        } else {
            $get('<%=gridView1.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
            $get('<%=gridView2.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Now the next problem start here again- Script is woking fine on Chrome and IE 10, but IE above 10, it can't find the method, add_BeginRequest()**.

PS: I don't want to use paging concept in the page for now, but looking for some alternate options to cop with this problem.

Do I have any other option to implement the same